# need help translating SQL to ORM calls

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to translate the sql below in to django orm calls or do I have to use raw sql?

thanks for any help

my models:

`class Parent(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Child(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=128)`

my sql:

`select *
from parent as p
  left join child as c on p.id = c.parent_id and c.slug in ('s0','s1','s2')
where p.id not in (select p.id
                   from parent as p
                     inner join child as c on p.id = c.parent_id and c.slug = 's3' and c.value = 'v3')
order by p.slug`

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__slug__in=['s0','s1','s2']).exclude(child__slug='s3', child__value='v3').order_by('slug')
```

Should do the same, though excluding where child.slug == 's3', is unnecessary when it's not in the `__in` array to be included in the first place.

**UPDATE**

To include parents with no child as well, use `Q` objects in your filter:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Parent.objects.filter(Q(child__isnull=True) | Q(child__slug__in=['s0','s1','s2']))
```

Comment: thanks, I doubt that this statement will return parents that do not have children at all, but I do need these parents as well...

Comment: getting a child from a parent returned by this query results in an additional database hit. the problem that I am trying to solve is often referred to as "backwards select_related ()".I need to get the children as well as their parents (including parents with no children), and I want to do it in a single query similar to the one that I posted. I saw some solutions on the web that use dictionaries etc, but I find them inefficient simply because they use extra memory to store these relations...

Comment: You need either `prefetch_related` in Django 1.4+ (not yet released) or django-batch-select (https://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select). It still won't be one query, but either of those will get you down to two instead of 1+N.